# Exception handler works for doGet(), but not for doPost()

Tags: servlets, exception

I have a servlet api where I used to throw my own exceptions from servlets level

When I throw exception from doGet method everything works fine and exception handler catches and processed my exception. the problem ocures when I throw exception from doPost method. in this case unfortunatelly I never see error page

web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type >
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

exception handler

```
@WebServlet("/ErrorHandler")
public class ErrorHandler extends HttpServlet {

    private final Logger logger;

    public ErrorHandler() {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorHandler.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);
        logger.error("occurred exception: ", throwable);
        httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Servlet

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
    throw new UserException("error message");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `ErrorHandler`

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Throwable throwable = (Throwable) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);
    logger.error("occurred exception: ", throwable);
    httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

To avoid code duplication consider creating third method

```
private void processError(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Throwable throwable = (Throwable) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);
    logger.error("occurred exception: ", throwable);
    httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

and invoke it from both `doGet()` and `doPost()`

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    processError(req, resp);      
}

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    processError(req, resp);     
}
```